# Any tips on debugging problems with the secondary sort in Hadoop MapReduce job?

Tags: java, sorting, hadoop, mapreduce

I believe (believed?) I understand how secondary sort works in Hadoop. I created an intermediate key consisting of 4 fields. I partition by the first field, group by the first and second, and sort by all 4.

It looks like I nailed grouping and partitioning down, but the values come into reducer out of order.

Any ideas on how to approach debugging of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, it appears that static code review either manually or using tools works good. I believe I broke the rule: when overriding `compareTo()`, don't forget to override `equals()` and `hashCode()`. I'll keep everyone posted if fixing this solved the problem.

Comment: Nobody came up with alternative proposals over the weekend, so I'm accepting my own answer.